# What is this Lisp dialect, used in GCC internals?

Tags: programming-languages

What programming language is this? It's a Lisp dialect used by GCC internals.

```
(define_insn "*call_symbol"
   [(call (mem:DI (match_operand:DI 0 "" ""))
          (match_operand 1 "" ""))
    (use (match_operand 2 "" ""))
    (clobber (reg:DI LR_REGNUM))]
   "GET_CODE (operands[0]) == SYMBOL_REF
    && !aarch64_is_long_call_p (operands[0])"
   "bl\\t%a0"
   [(set_attr "type" "call")]
)
```

[Link to source file](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=gcc/config/aarch64/aarch64.md;hb=172881b016150e383411bfbbe8bf757bff62f22b)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called machine description files. These `.md` files are used to generate a significant part of the C (now C++) code of the back end.

BTW, you could also customize GCC using a Lisp-like language: [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)

Some documentation is linked from [MELT documentation page](http://gcc-melt.org/docum.html), and to get a global picture about GCC I strongly recommend taking several hours on the (Indian) [GCC resource center](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/grc/).

This (mine) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26167384/841108) contains pictures which might be helpful to you.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, MD is not a Turing-complete programming language but rather a configuration language / DSL with Lispy syntax; and it is not compiled but transpiled to C++ code?

Comment: It is a DSL with Lispy syntax. I don't know if it is not Turing-complete. AFAIK, you can put some C or C++ code inside `.md` files... so it may become Turing-complete...